# Using Microsoft Word's spell / grammar check with php

Tags: php, spell-checking

I am searching from 1 day to find is there any way to use Microsoft spell check and grammar check from php. i tried to use dotnet class and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word but failed to use the word spell checker. Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this, but this is an example posted on the PHP COM Functions page, have you tried this yet?

```
<?php
function SpellCheck($input)
{
    $word=new COM("word.application") or die("Cannot create Word object");
    $word->Visible=false;
    $word->WindowState=2;
    $word->DisplayAlerts=false;
    $doc=$word->Documents->Add();
    $doc->Content=$input;
    $doc->CheckSpelling();
    $result= $doc->SpellingErrors->Count;
    if($result!=0)
    {
        echo "Input text contains misspelled words.\n\n";
        for($i=1; $i <= $result; $i++)
        {       
            echo "Original Word: " .$doc->SpellingErrors[$i]->Text."\n";
            $list=$doc->SpellingErrors[$i]->GetSpellingSuggestions();
            echo "Suggestions: ";
            for($j=1; $j <= $list->Count; $j++)
            {
                $correct=$list->Item($j);
                echo $correct->Name.",";
            }
            echo "\n\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No spelling mistakes found.";
    }
    $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);
    $word->Quit();
    $word->Release();
    $word=null;
}

$str="Hellu world. There is a spellling error in this sentence.";
SpellCheck($str);
?>
```

Source: [PHP: COM Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php)

Comment: Thanks James Hunt, but when i am trying to run the code i am struck with the error  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `word.application'

Comment: Does the system have the word COM object installed? - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=22276

Comment: When i am trying the com with word.application to show the version it was working fine, but when i am trying with the above code, page loading continuously without showing any error or result.

Comment: Got the solution actually it is not working in ms office 2007 when i tried it in ms office 2010 it works perfectly.Thanks James

Comment: No problem, if this answer is correct, mind clicking so for other users? In case this problem happens to others.